# Count combinations in indicators

Tags: r, if-statement, matrix

I am trying to figure out a more efficient way of calculating the number of correct combinations within the indicators.

**Here is my data:**

```
head(data)
   email_flag home_number_flag mobile_flag
1:  incorrect        incorrect     correct
2:  incorrect        incorrect   incorrect
3:  incorrect        incorrect   incorrect
4:  incorrect        incorrect   incorrect
5:  incorrect        incorrect   incorrect
6:  incorrect        incorrect   incorrect
```

**My current approach with an ifelse statement:**

```
data <- mutate(data, number_of_correct_flags =
    +                            ifelse(email_flag == "correct" & mobile_flag == "correct", 2, 
    +                            ifelse(email_flag != "correct" & mobile_flag == "correct", 1, 
    +                            ifelse(email_flag == "correct" & mobile_flag != "correct", 1,
    +                            ifelse(email_flag != "correct" & mobile_flag != "correct", 0,
    +                                                        
    +                            ifelse(home_number_flag == "correct" & mobile_flag == "correct", 2, 
    +                            ifelse(home_number_flag != "correct" & mobile_flag == "correct", 1, 
    +                            ifelse(home_number_flag == "correct" & mobile_flag != "correct", 1,
    +                            ifelse(home_number_flag != "correct" & mobile_flag != "correct", 0, 
    +                                                                                    
    +                            ifelse(email_flag == "correct" & mobile_flag == "correct", 2, 
    +                            ifelse(email_flag != "correct" & mobile_flag == "correct", 1, 
    +                            ifelse(email_flag == "correct" & mobile_flag != "correct", 1,
    +                            ifelse(email_flag != "correct" & mobile_flag != "correct", 0, 
    +                                   
    +                            ifelse(email_flag == "correct" & mobile_flag == "correct" & home_number_flag == "correct", 3, 
    +                            ifelse(email_flag != "correct" & mobile_flag != "correct" & home_number_flag != "correct", 0, "check")))))))))))))))
```

**Result**:

```
head(data)
      email_flag home_number_flag mobile_flag number_of_correct_flags
    1  incorrect        incorrect     correct                       1
    2  incorrect        incorrect   incorrect                       0
    3  incorrect        incorrect   incorrect                       0
    4  incorrect        incorrect   incorrect                       0
    5  incorrect        incorrect   incorrect                       0
    6  incorrect        incorrect   incorrect                       0
```

Obviouslly, this becomes problematic as the number of indicators grows.

Any thoughts on a more efficient approach?

Comment: Please show an example with all the combinations.  I think it is better to create a  key/val dataset and then do a join

Comment: use apply `apply(data[, c("email_flag", "home_number_flag", "mobile_flag")], 1, function(x) sum(x == "correct"))`

Comment: @amatsuo_net yeah. this one works great. thank you.

Comment: Well if your data are nicely formatted then maybe `rowSums(data=="correct")`

Comment: @akrun im sure if I quite follow you on the key/val dataset idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is a `data.table`, we can use the `data.table` methods

```
library(data.table)
data[, number_of_correct_flags := Reduce(`+`, lapply(.SD, `==`, "correct")), 
          .SDcols = c("email_flag", "home_number_flag", "mobile_flag")]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
data$number_of_correct_flags <- rowSums(data == "correct")
```

In case if your data contains some other variables apart from these flag variables you will need to drop them from the `data` inside `rowSums` call e.g.  with `select(data, matches("flag$"))`.